# theme_menu_tree override single link

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm trying to override the HTML output of a single menu_link only when the user is anonymous. The following code is based on [this](https://github.com/Taskulu/deskulu/blob/6e3681704dc06d93a9c6688fa0e3e68626a7bea1/sites/all/themes/ht/template.php#L256) by deskulu developers.

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__secondary(&$variables) {
  $variables['tree'] = i18n_menu_translated_tree('user-menu');
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    $children = element_children($variables['tree']);
    foreach($children as $index => $id) {
      $classes = ['btn', 'navbar-btn'];
      if ($index == count($children) - 1) {
        $classes[] = 'btn-warning';
        $variables['tree'][$id]['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'] = $classes;
        $element = $variables['tree'][$id];
        $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
        return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '><div>' . $output . "</div></li>\n";
      }
    }
  }
  return render($variables['tree']);
}
```

The result, however, is a correct rewrite of the single link but the disappearance of the others.

Also, I'm unable to print with `dpm()` the `$variables['tree']` object so it's a bit difficult to debug.

Comment: You should remove the "return" statement at the end of the "if" inside the "foreach" loop. You are returning some markup as soon as you find the item to overwrite, instead of returning the whole menu tree after the loop has finished.

Comment: Hi @dinopmi, the problem is that I don't know where to "store"  the item override, because, even if I remove the `return`, I'm not able to use `dpm()` in order to visualise the structure of  `$variables['tree']`.